# Custom segue that 'finishes' early?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue, cgrect

I'm looking to implement a custom segue that pushes to a UIViewController, but completes before the new UIViewController fully fills the screen, leaving some of the source view controller still in view and functional. (For example; new view controller covers half of the user interface).

I'm keen to use a segue rather than a view that is moved using CGRect, Quartz framework method, or similar, as constraints get messy really easily, unless a custom segue could utilise such methods(?)

Any pointers greatly welcomed! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this task you would use a [container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6), which manages and displays the content of multiple other view controllers at a time while letting them interact with their views like normal. An example of this would be the [UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), which displays two view controllers' views at a time, one on each side of the screen. You can design segues that swap out one view controller of the multiple on display in a container view controller, similarly to the Replace Segue implemented by Apple to swap out a UISplitViewController's detail view controller (the one on the right hand side).